# Can a function be declared as pure at definition?

Tags: javascript, webpack, side-effects

According to [Webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#mark-a-function-call-as-side-effect-free):

> It can be put in front of **function calls** to mark them as side-effect-free. Arguments passed to the function are not being marked by the annotation and may need to be marked individually.

Can we write PURE function at declaration ? Something like:

```js
var max = /*#__PURE__*/(a,b) => { return (a>b)?a:b }
```

If yes, what is the right syntax?

Comment: What do you mean by "declaration"? Is it `*.d.ts` file or something else?

Comment: No I just talk about function declaration : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no native way you can declare function as `pure` in JavaScript.

TypeScript has a proposal to introduce `pure` keyword for functions and methods, but currently this is just a draft. You can read the whole thread, if you want [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7770). The thread contains a [comment with draft proposal description](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7770#issuecomment-334919251). When and whether at all this idea will be implemented is very hard to say.